# C output confusion

Tags: c, while-loop, max, scanf, min

I'm trying to learn some C, but it's a pain.
I have this task: 'Write a C program to determine the minmum and maximum of a sequence of integer numbers on input, terminged by the string "done".' Very simple task, just like the input:
5
2
9
done
However the output is wrong, and I can't figure it out. I would very much appreciate some help. Thx!

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char line[1000];
    int val, min = 10, max = -1;
    while ( 1 ) {
      scanf("%d", &val);
      if (val < min) min = val;
      if (val > max) max = val;
      scanf("%4s", line);
      if (strcmp("done", line) == 0) break;
    }
    printf("Maximum %d\n", max);
    printf("Minimum %d", min);
}
```

Both of the environments I tested the code in will output Max 9, Min 5.
Can someone explain what is going on?
[image: onlinegdb]
[image]

Comment: Take *one* input to the **string**. If it is "done" then break. Otherwise convert it to an integer value.

Comment: Your input of `2` was consumed by `line` input and since it not `Done` was ignored.

Comment: In every iteration you do two things: You read a number and a string. So you first read the number `5`, then you read the string `2` and compare it to `done`, then you read the number `9`, then you read the string `done` and compare it to `done`. So of _numbers_ you only ever read `5` and `9`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the while loop

```
while ( 1 ) {
  scanf("%d", &val);
  if (val < min) min = val;
  if (val > max) max = val;
  scanf("%4s", line);
  if (strcmp("done", line) == 0) break;
}
```

you have to enter a string after each input of a number.

So the second number 2 is considered as an input of a string.

Also integer numbers can be negative less than -1 or positive greater than 10. So this declaration

```
int val, min = 10, max = -1;
```

does not make sense.

Instead you can read all numbers in a character array and then to use for example the function `atoi` to convert the entered string to a number.

For example a simple program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char line[16];
    int min = 0, max = 0;
    int empty = 1;

    while ( scanf( "%15s", line ) == 1 && strcmp( line, "done" ) != 0 )
    {
        int val = atoi( line );

        if ( empty )
        {
            min   = val;
            max   = val;
            empty = 0;
        }
        else if ( max < val )
        {
            max = val;
        }
        else if ( val < min )
        {
            min = val;
        }
    }
     
    if ( empty )
    {
        puts( "The sequence of numbers is empty." );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Maximum %d\n", max );
        printf( "Minimum %d\n", min );
    }
}
```

You will need to enter the string `"done"` only once to break the loop. In all other cases you will need to enter only integer numbers.